# iOs 6 different storyboards for iphone5 and other iphones

Tags: iphone, uistoryboard, iphone-5

I have been developing an app for iOs5. Now that the new iPhone is here (with iOs 6) I ran the app in the simulator (iPhone 4 - inch retina) and much of the views don't display properly... What is the best course of action? Is it possible to create another storyboard for the 4-inch display? Or setting up the struts and springs will auto-adjust the  views to fit the new display better?

Comment: I do believe setting the the struts and springs correctly should resolve this issue, I haven't actually done anything for the new iPhone yet so this is only a guess.

Comment: I will try the struts and spring ... I hope it works ... if not ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After testing this myself it looks like the struts and springs will fix this for the most part. If however you are creating your views programmatically you will most likely have to make some changes if you put static widths and heights. I ran into an instance of this where I have `UIWebViews` being populated in a `UiScrollView` and it did not fill up the screen since I was setting the height statically 323. Here is what the adjustment was:

> CGRect rect = webView.frame;
>   rect.size.height = myScrollView.bounds.size.height; (this used to be 323)
>   rect.size.width = myScrollView.bounds.size.width;

This was able to fix the height setting since `myScrollview` was set to fill the entire display.

Comment: Was almost pulling my hair out as I've already tried to use springs and struts, but it did not work. After reading your answer I went to try once again and realized I was making changes on a wrong view controller. I hate myself, and I vote up :D

Answer (score 1):

You should set springs or struts for our views in the size inspector so that they resize correctly with the scene. There's a button in the lower right corner of the canvas to stretch or compress all top level full screen views between iPhone 5 and pre iPhone 5 sizes. You can use this to verify that your springs and struts are setup correctly.

If your minimum deployment target is iOS 6.0+, you can use auto layout instead of springs and struts. This will give you much more fine grained control over how your interface resizes.